# How to remove ActionSheet borderRadius NativeBase

Tags: react-native, native-base, chakra-ui, actionsheet

I am working on react native and using native-base (v3.0.*) for the design part. I need to remove the top border-radius from the Actionsheet and need something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After diving deep into the API and package code. I was able to fix the issue.

Here's what worked for me.

**Solution 1**

```
 <Actionsheet isOpen={props.isOpen} onClose={props.onClose}>
        <Actionsheet.Content
          roundedTop={0} // this is the prop you need to add.
          padding={0}
          bg="red.700"
```

**Solution 2:**

In your theme file you can do something like this:

```
 ActionsheetContent: {
      baseStyle: {
          roundedTop: 0,
      },
 },
```

Hope this helped you. Happy Coding :)